# Can you say shechechiyanu on something you might return?

Tags: halacha, clothing, transactions, shehecheyanu

Say you bought a nice suit. Can you say shechechiyanu on it if there's a possibility that you might return it.

If you already did say shechichiyanu on it, are you allowed to return it?

Answer (score 2):

In general, one says Shehecheyanu because of the joy one feels - to thank Hashem for allowing us to arrive to that time and feel that joy. **Therefore, if you feel joyous after the acquisition of the suit, and it is a piece of clothing with a degree of importance, you should say the blessing** (see sources [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/06/23/shehecheyanu-on-new-clothes-which-clothes/)). If you already know that you might not keep the suit - then better to wait if it mars your joy.

This being said

- the suit has to be desirable to you - not just to other people (see [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/shehecheyanu/))
- there are opinions from R Chayim Palagi and the Kaf Hachayim (OC 223:18) saying (in the context of a house bought on credit) that one does not make a bracha because of the possibility he might have to return it to the seller (cited by [yeshiva.co](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/outershiur.asp?id=27066))

Of course, don't trust anything you read here and [ask your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) in real life.